# How to finish child activity android

Tags: android

Login Activity

```
mGoogleBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, GoogleAuthentication.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Then in my GoogleAuthentication Activity , googleSignIn method is called in oncreate

```
  private void googleSignIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, GOOGLE_RC_SIGN_IN);
    }
```

Under this method , I tried to kill my child activity but its not getting killed

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == GOOGLE_RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);

            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            }else {
                finishActivity(requestCode);
                this.finish();
                Intent intent = new Intent(GoogleAuthentication.this, LoginActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
                Toast.makeText(GoogleAuthentication.this, "Google Authentication Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

I want this child activity to be killed when I press back button .... right now , its not killed and when I open someother activity this google sign intent activity pops in again.

Please help , thansk for you time.

Comment: finishActivity(requestCode); call in if case also or declare global

Comment: tried this , not working 
if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                finishActivity(requestCode);
                this.finish();
                Toast.makeText(GoogleAuthentication.this, "Google cancel", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

Comment: where you call googleSignIn() ? its fired on onActivityResult properly??

Comment: use addFlag in this approach it will clear your activity stack. 'intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);'